# Heyzap interstitial ads in every app

Tags: malware

I noticed when I start an app, often an Heyzap interstitial ad appears (I had the Heyzap app but removed it 2 days ago).

Today I ran my own app that I've compiled from the Android SDK that definitely does not have any Heyzap code, but still, the banner appeared.

I think the problem arrived after installing "Lost Temple Jump" game from Google Play. It was asking for permission to push notifications. I said No.

My device is not rooted, is it possible that these games root my device and started to insert Heyzap banner to every other app ?

---

### Screenshots:

[image: Google Play with malware banner] [image: my app with no banner code has banner]

---

### Running processes list:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME

root      1     0     556    424   ffffffff 00000000 S /init

root      2     0     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kthreadd

root      3     2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ksoftirqd/0

root      6     2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S migration/0

root      16    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S khelper

root      17    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S suspend_sys_syn

root      18    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S suspend

root      20    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/203-msmdata

root      21    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S sync_supers

root      22    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S bdi-default

root      23    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kblockd

root      24    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S msm_slim_ctrl_r

root      25    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S khubd

root      26    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/84-msm_iomm

root      27    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/84-msm_iomm

root      28    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/96-msm_iomm

root      29    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/96-msm_iomm

root      30    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/94-msm_iomm

root      31    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/94-msm_iomm

root      32    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/92-msm_iomm

root      33    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/92-msm_iomm

root      34    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/100-msm_iom

root      35    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/100-msm_iom

root      36    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/86-msm_iomm

root      37    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/86-msm_iomm

root      38    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/90-msm_iomm

root      39    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/90-msm_iomm

root      40    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/88-msm_iomm

root      41    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/102-msm_iom

root      42    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/102-msm_iom

root      43    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/98-msm_iomm

root      44    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/98-msm_iomm

root      45    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/243-msm_iom

root      46    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/243-msm_iom

root      47    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/269-msm_iom

root      48    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/269-msm_iom

root      49    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S l2cap

root      50    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S a2mp

root      51    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S cfg80211

root      52    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/644-earjack

root      53    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S modem_notifier

root      54    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smd_channel_clo

root      55    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smsm_cb_wq

root      57    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S qmi

root      58    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S nmea

root      59    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S msm_ipc_router

root      60    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S apr_driver

root      61    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/337-mdm sta

root      62    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/334-mdm pbl

root      64    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kswapd0

root      65    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S fsnotify_mark

root      66    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S cifsiod

root      67    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S crypto

root      81    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mdp_dma_wq

root      82    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mdp_vsync_wq

root      83    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mdp_pipe_ctrl_w

root      84    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mdp_cursor_ctrl

root      85    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hdmi_hdcp

root      86    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/111-hdmi_ms

root      87    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S dtv_work

root      88    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S vidc_worker_que

root      89    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S vidc_timer_wq

root      90    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smux_notify_wq

root      91    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smux_tx_wq

root      92    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smux_rx_wq

root      93    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smux_loopback_w

root      94    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S diag_wq

root      95    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsic_diag_wq

root      96    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsic_2_diag_wq

root      97    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smux_diag_wq

root      98    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S diag_cntl_wq

root      99    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S diag_dci_wq

root      100   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kgsl-3d0

root      101   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S anx7808_work

root      102   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/645-anx7808

root      104   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/330-wcd9xxx

root      109   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S usbnet

root      112   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mdm_bridge

root      113   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ks_bridge:1

root      114   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ks_bridge:2

root      115   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ks_bridge:3

root      116   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ks_bridge:4

root      117   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S k_rmnet_mux_wor

root      118   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S f_mtp

root      119   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S file-storage

root      120   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S uether

root      121   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S touch_wq

root      123   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S iewq

root      124   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kinteractiveup

root      125   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S binder

root      126   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mmcqd/0

root      130   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S krfcommd

root      131   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S rq_stats

root      132   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S deferwq

root      135   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S vibrator

root      136   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S fsa8008

root      137   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/369-fsa8008

root      138   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/371-fsa8008

root      139   1     476    312   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/ueventd

root      141   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p21

root      142   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit

root      147   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p22

root      148   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit

root      152   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p23

root      153   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit

root      154   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p20

root      155   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit

system    165   1     884    340   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/servicemanager

root      166   1     4008   664   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/vold

system    167   1     1084   456   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/qcks

root      168   1     10868  1696  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/netd

root      169   1     976    576   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/debuggerd

radio     170   1     14416  2848  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/rild

system    171   1     96384  8688  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/surfaceflinger

root      172   1     827808 39576 ffffffff 00000000 S zygote

drm       173   1     13308  3476  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/drmserver

media     174   1     48868  8648  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/mediaserver

install   175   1     896    492   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/installd

keystore  177   1     3248   1052  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/keystore

nobody    178   1     2144   548   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/rmt_storage

radio     179   1     6320   640   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/bridgemgrd

radio     180   1     7388   440   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/qmuxd

radio     181   1     7580   700   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/netmgrd

root      182   1     20848  828   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/thermald

root      183   1     6200   472   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/mpdecision

root      189   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsicctl0

root      190   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsicctl1

root      191   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsicctl2

root      192   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S hsicctl3

nobody    193   1     10444  668   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/sensors.qcom

media_rw  194   1     2708   988   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/sdcard

camera    195   1     4976   2472  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon

system    197   1     2132   324   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/qseecomd

shell     198   1     4544   280   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd

system    244   197   4232   432   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/qseecomd

system    553   172   1016800 92148 ffffffff 00000000 S system_server

system    575   167   1064   476   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/efsks

root      577   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ehci_wq

root      578   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/337-hsic_pe

system    586   575   2892   2108  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/ks

root      873   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S WD_Thread

root      874   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S MC_Thread

root      875   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S TX_Thread

root      876   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S RX_Thread

wifi      912   1     3196   1824  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/wpa_supplicant

u0_a57    966   172   906368 78664 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.systemui

u0_a49    1063  172   867320 33476 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.phasebeam

u0_a34    1078  172   888692 58356 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.inputmethod.latin

u0_a23    1094  172   1008768 48316 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.location

radio     1111  172   890824 48388 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.phone

nfc       1134  172   858504 27604 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.nfc

u0_a35    1148  172   941812 83760 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.launcher

nfc       1191  172   838592 22292 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.nfc:handover

u0_a23    1206  172   894992 38360 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.gapps

u0_a23    2408  172   853692 30292 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gsf.login

root      2882  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S msm_sat0

u0_a52    3224  172   871816 43784 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.plus

root      4232  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S flush-179:0

u0_a15    10631 172   841044 27908 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.media

u0_a0     11406 172   873656 33396 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.acore

root      11868 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S msm_sat1

u0_a41    12007 172   907300 44000 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.mms

u0_a85    12022 172   883760 46120 ffffffff 00000000 S com.facebook.katana

u0_a10    14365 172   1143480 119444 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome

u0_i3     14790 172   978188 107236 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process3

u0_a20    15454 172   882408 50200 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gallery3d

u0_i6     15558 172   959980 92904 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process1

u0_i8     15882 172   975888 110908 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0

u0_a60    16597 172   909308 48052 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

u0_a86    19209 172   892496 66084 ffffffff 00000000 S com.vkontakte.android

u0_a77    21519 172   874672 49400 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.dialer

root      23312 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:1

root      23483 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:4

dhcp      23515 1     916    456   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/dhcpcd

root      24028 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:0

root      24246 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:5

root      24257 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:16

root      24260 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:19

root      24268 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:27

root      24276 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:37

root      25927 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:3

u0_a114   27884 172   877056 47332 ffffffff 00000000 S com.facebook.orca

u0_a84    28165 172   923156 83408 ffffffff 00000000 S com.skype.raider

u0_a50    29850 172   924516 78784 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.vending

u0_a98    30061 172   859416 30808 ffffffff 00000000 S com.whatsapp

root      30273 2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:2

u0_a13    30482 172   835224 22172 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.defcontainer

u0_a27    30513 172   835468 22516 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.partnersetup

u0_a43    30533 172   835268 21956 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.musicfx

u0_a23    30553 172   951380 33212 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gms

u0_a105   30580 172   839056 26348 ffffffff 00000000 S com.potyomkin.talkingkote

u0_a144   30599 172   871284 38764 ffffffff 00000000 S net.mobilecraft.football

u0_a145   30622 172   840464 25272 ffffffff 00000000 S net.mobilecraft.realbasketball

system    30816 172   842864 25720 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.settings

u0_a40    30887 172   838084 24220 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.uploader

u0_a67    30904 172   866464 30244 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.youtube

u0_a7     31082 172   836036 24164 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.providers.calendar

u0_a6     31096 172   844188 24432 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.calendar

u0_a140   31168 172   837860 23104 ffffffff 00000000 S com.gismeteo.client

shell     31203 198   1132   468   00000000 b6e88040 R ps

u0_a96    31346 172   904276 102608 ffffffff 00000000 S com.topface.topface
```

[image]

Comment: What device? What android version? Have not heard of a such app actually rooting your phone in this way, in fact I'd be sceptical if it did! Push notifications like this, Airpush is another, are a nuisance and should not be used nor installed! In future, *always* read the permissions required before attempting to install a app.

Comment: Google Nexus 4. Android 4.2.2. Ads have Heyzap logo in right bottom corner I think. Wondering what technique they used to insert ads in my own app.

Comment: That's interesting, you are using Google Ads right? And  this Heyzap thingy over-rode it and placed an ad-push in that spot? Only way to get rid of it is to perform factory reset...

Comment: The app I developed was single activity and label. No ads. Just default app that eclipse created for me. I got these ad on Android desktop and in Play Market. Actually right now it usually popups in Google Play.

Answer (score 5):

I am one of the co-founders of Heyzap. I wanted to clarify a few things and see if I could help.

Firstly this is not intentional in any way. Heyzap is an in game Ad network and those Ads should only be showing up in the game developer we directly work with.

The problem is caused by a faulty integration either by the developers or due to an old SDK, this is pretty unusual and we haven't seen many reports of this. The game must be running in the background and calling our Ads to show.

A quick fix is to identify the game that is running and causing this and uninstall it. From looking at the process list the only two potentials I see are: net.mobilecraft.football and net.mobilecraft.realbasketball.

If its easier for you, can you share your Android ID with me and I can ensure that you don't see any Ads from us.

"Lost Temple Jump" has never published our Ads as far as I know, so is unlikely to be responsible.

As action points from us:

1. We are going to look in to putting more protection in our SDK to prevent this.
2. We are going to talk to the developer about updating their SDK and not showing Ads when not in the foreground. This initially seems like it shouldn't be possible in Android but something for us to investigate. I am sure this is accidental on their part too.

Comment: Mobilecraft games have special permissions to startup at boot. So they are candidates for doing that. Even if I reboot then they always reside in memory. Strategy how ads are shown changing. First it was when some app starts once per 2 days. Then it was showing more often but inside of Google Play. So it seems it monitors what app is to. Finally they showed other non Heyzap ads. I hope my personal information like passwords and emails are save. If you block ads for my Android ID it will make detecting that even more complex.

Comment: I just checked the Google Play Store. They don't appear to have on boot startup permission. Did they used to have that?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. My phone is not rooted. I listed processes after reboot.

Comment: I have notification in tray now. Some times I have 2 same pushes now https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobilecraft.birthdaygift  It is mobilecraft game. It is clear who is doing that!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that these games root my phone and started to insert
>   Heyzap banner to every other app?

No, rooting requires user intervention, there is no known method of stealthily rooting without the user's knowledge/permission.

The moral of the story is:

- boycott all forms of air-push like notifications and post a 1 star review for that app that caused havoc - Temple Run app - IIRC there was bogus versions on the playstore, I remember reading it on reddit's android subreddit about this.
- Read the permissions listing on what the app requires, if in doubt, check the reviews, and google around a bit possibly, using Reddit's Android subreddit and ask in there or AndroidApps subreddit for other's opinions, someone will be bound to give you a pointer or two...

To put yourself out of misery, do a factory reset and wipe the cache/data in order to "regain control". You will lose your data in the process.

Comment: "rooting requires user intervention": that's usually true, but there are security vulnerabilities on some devices, such as the exynos4 camera bug (exploitable on Samsung Galaxy S3, for example).

Comment: Is Google Nexus 4. Android 4.2.2 running on Exynos? Also, "*I think the problem arrived after installing "Lost Temple Jump" game from Google Play*"... As for that vulnerability you mentioned - this is more specific to the software running on exynos chipset for all 6 of samsung devices which is madness in that it was not plugged or fixed officially (Was patched into CM 10.1 by codeworx)! There's a similar one for the Qualcomm MSM devices - Framebuffer overflow exploit which got patched in shortly around the time of Masterkey exploit.

Comment: No, I mention the exynos4 vuln simply as an example. I don't know of one for the Nexus 4, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. I'm only making a caveat to your claim that rooting requires user intervention.

Comment: Yes. Factory Reset is something I must do. Is there anyway to learn what happened? Such banner inside Google POlay is not normal. To open dialog activity in app you must list it in AndroidManifest.xml. So had that virus modified manifest of all apps including google play. Should I change password of my google account?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the app you uninstalled wasn't the one responsible for the ads. When an ad appears, immediately go to the **Settings** app and look in the list of running apps to see if one of those is suspicious. Try force-closing it and see if the ads go away temporarily.

Alternatively, as you have the development tools installed, it might be useful to examine the device's log from when the annoying dialog appears: if there's any relevant log output, you'll be able to see what app it is coming from.

Comment: I did `adb ps` It lists all processes. Process list is under screenshot.

Comment: And did that help you solve the problem? If not, please try the steps I suggested instead.

Comment: I am not sure how it will help me identify the app. Ad appears once per per or per two days.

Comment: Because the banner's not inside another app. It's inside the responsible app, just displaying on top of another app, like a dialog. So when the dialog is displayed, the responsible app is running and will show up in that list. It'll be much easier to identify from that list than from the `ps` output.

Comment: Interesting! I should try to open dialog like that from my app. I think it is impossible.