# How do I wipe Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4

I think I got virus and have no idea how to get rid of it.
[Heyzap interstitial ads in every app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50091/heyzap-ads-in-every-app)

I think wiping phone will delete virus.

I have Nexus 4 with Android 4.3

Phone is not rooted but I am ready to root as I got virus without root.

**PS I know about Factory Reset button**

https://support.google.com/nexus/4/answer/2936226?hl=en
I am not sure if that is enough. I seen some ppl wipe phone from command line from PC. By uploading new firmware from PC. Is that different from Factory Reset button?
The reason is that I wish to delete virus that shows ads in Google Play, Desktop, etc

Answer (score 4):

Factory Reset will delete all your data, and restore your phone as if it were brand new.

On the other hand, flashing a new ROM is one way to change another version (usually to a higher version or a custom ROM) of Android. In this case, data is retained, unless you do a full wipe, which is equivalent to a Factory Reset.

A Factory Reset is sufficient in your case.

**Other questions:**
[What is hard reset and what is factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/what-is-hard-reset-and-what-is-factory-reset)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to wipe is install the factory image from [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam) This completely formats/wipes your phone (including user data by default). This would guarantee that you get rid of the virus. I'd suggest doing a factory reset first though as that is a simpler method which may rid you of this virus.

To install the factory image you would need to [Unlock your bootloader](https://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html#booting-into-fastboot-mode) (which wipes your device in the process, the same as a factoy reset would). You can then run the flash-all.bat (or flash-all.sh if you're on linux) from the factory image zip and this should perform all the necessary steps for you